# Hibernet - How to perform a select with some filters

Tags: hibernate

I need something really simple, but need your help to do this

I am using Hibernate with Oracle Database, and I am performing a Full query using "select b from Biossimilar_Entity b" as you can see bellow

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<BiossimilarEntity> getAll() {
    Query query = em.createQuery("select b from Biossimilar_Entity b");
    return (ArrayList<BiossimilarEntity>) query.getResultList();
}
```

But I need two things, I need to apply to filters using Date Field;

```
    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Calendar data_bio;
```

First:

I need to get this list ordered by date , from the first to last.. Examplo: 01012015 then 01022015, then 01032015, etc. DD/MM/YYYY

Second

I need to get same list , but I only need the last 12 months.... when I get this list today 27/07/2016 , i will need all months starting in 01/07/2015

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

it is easier to implement Native Query :

```
String stringQuery= "SELECT b from Biossimilar_Entity b WHERE b.data_bio BETWEEN NOW() and DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 year) ORDER BY b.b.data_bio";

Query query = em.createNativeQuery(stringQuery);
```